# Write dynamic @fontface CSS in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm currently rebuilding my type foundry's website using Nuxt on top of VueJS and was trying to minimize the amount CSS to write.

In particular, I'd like to generate all @fontface CSS directly from the data fed by the backend.
Imagine my data being something like

```
{
 fontData: 
   fontName: name
   fontWoff: /path
   fontWeight: 400
}
```

Is there a way to generate style tags inside .vue components with dynamic fontfaces? 
Something like

```
@fontface {
 font-family: {{ fontData.fontName }};
 src: {{ fontData.fontWoff }};
 font-weight: {{ fontData.fontWeight }};
}
```

What would be a possible workaroud?
Trying to avoid having to write new @fontfaces every time we add a new typeface in the backend.

Thanks!